# How to extract values from list without having to iterate the whole list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

Consider a list of lists, like this:

```
my_list = [[0,"zero"], [0,"zero 2x"], [1,"one"], [2,"two"]]
```

What is the most efficient way to get a subset based on the first value? I want to get:

```
zero_list = ["zero", "zero 2x"]
```

Of course one could iterate the whole list, but with a few thousand values it seems inefficient.

```
zero_list = []
for i in my_list:
    if i[0] == 0:
        zero_list.append(i[1])
```

Is there a more efficient way? Would a lambda expression can do this?

Comment: Are you going to do the same for `1` and `2` or just for `0`?

Comment: This is just an example. I need to extract a few values out of a long list. Let's say the numbers go up to 1,000 but I need 0-3.

Comment: Why not use list comprehensions? E.g. ``zero_list = [j for i, j in my_list if i == 0]``

Comment: Is the `my_list` sorted by first element?

Comment: @DocDriven I think this is useful. But is it shorthand for still iterating the whole list?

Comment: @DocDriven a list comprehension is usually not any more efficient than a regular loop - it's just syntactic sugar for when you're building a list in a loop.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I am aware of that, but for this simple case it is the fastest AND the most readable solution.

Comment: @DocDriven Maybe we're saying the same thing, but I want to clarify that a listcomp is not the fastest. Run [this](https://replit.com/@PranavHosangadi/PandasNotAlwaysFaster#comprehension.py) a hundred times and you will get near-identical results for both approaches. This multi-line loop is no faster or slower than its corresponding list comprehension. When OP's asking for the most efficient way, suggesting a list comprehension instead of their loop gives the false impression that the listcomp is more efficient.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I agree with you that this might give a false impression. What I was trying to say is the differences between both solutions are negligible with list comps having the added benefit being more readable in this case.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I am curious: can you explain to me why the list comprehension is consistently slower (not much, but still!) despite a list comp having fewer bytecode instructions? This is somewhat counter-intuitive to me :/

Comment: @DocDriven I don't see the same thing you do - for me, there seems to be no pattern as to which is faster, although I haven't done a detailed statistical analysis to definitively say one way or another. Good question though - maybe someone more experienced with the internals of Python than I can answer it?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: If you want to get all elements from the list without iteration, and you can fetch all elements at once from the list as it's separate original data type (not list as an ouput again) then below is the better solution:

```
my_list=[1,2,3,4]
print(*my_list)

Output: 1 2 3 4
```

You can use *listname, which will produce all elements from the list separate

Answer (score 0):

you can transform the list to DataFrame and extract target values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns= ['value', 'char'])
df1 = df[df['value'] == 0].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: This is not faster. It takes time to parse a list into a dataframe. This time could be better spent just iterating over the list in a loop. [Proof on repl.it](https://replit.com/@PranavHosangadi/PandasNotAlwaysFaster#main.py) The exact times vary, but everywhere I have tried I see that looping is at least 4x faster than using pandas.